# C# generics copy constructor

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic class that i want to implement a copy constructor of

```
public abstract class  BaseClass<T>
{
     protected T Data { get; set; }
     protected BaseClass(T other)
     {
          this.Data = other.Data;
     }

}
```

I'm getting compilation error , that `other`

does not  have a field names `Data` .

I've thought of using dynamic , so the constructor signature will be BaseClass(dynamic other) , is there any other way?

Comment: dynamic won't work - `T` doesn't have a property called `Data`. You should either be accepting a `BaseClass<T>` into your constructor, or change the code to be `this.Data = other` (depending on your needs). However, this will be a shallow copy at best - how deep are you expecting your copy to go?

Comment: For generic purposes , I would like it be a deep copy, for that i would like to enforce an ICloneable on T

Comment: Well then just add a generic constraint to say that T must implement ICloneable - easy :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your *copy constructor* takes a `T` type argument, but you treat it as a `BaseClass<T>`.

Both of the following would solve your problem, but since you want to call it a *copy constructor*, the second is better for you:

```
public abstract class  BaseClass<T>
{
    protected T Data { get; set; }
    protected BaseClass(T other)
    {
        this.Data = other;
    }
}
```

**Second:**

```
public abstract class  BaseClass<T>
{
    protected T Data { get; set; }
    protected BaseClass(BaseClass<T> other)
    {
        this.Data = other.Data;
    }
}
```